# Evaluate a JQUERY statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this kind of script to evaluate my javascript code that is injected in the DOM

```
function wilEval(source) {

  if ('function' == typeof source) {
    source = '(' + source + ')();'
  }
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.textContent = source;
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  if (window.execScript) {
         window.execScript(source);
  }

}
```

it works in IE and other major browsers but my problem is the code to be evaluated is a jquery code like this `$("#<?php echo "utm".$thr_id; ?>").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);` So how can evaluate it like a normal javascript code? thanks

P.S. the php echo just produce a dynamic element id =)

Comment: Adding the php inline code dynamically to the DOM will not execute it server side.  The <?php... code is executed when the page is being rendered by PHP engine server, by the time you are in the client's browser, its too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is use [globalEval()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/)

```
function wilEval(source) {

  if ('function' == typeof source) {
    source = '(' + source + ')();'
  }


  if (window.execScript) {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
     script.textContent = source;
     document.body.appendChild(script);
     window.execScript(source);
  }else{
     jQuery.globalEval(source);
  }

}
```

Comment: can I use this on a external JS file? anyways the JS file that I will be making with this code is included in a html file that has jquery file included on it...

Answer (score 0):

so, your code is not a function but rather a `statement`

then, wrap it like that:

```
(function () { YOUR STATEMENT }());
```